# Mongodb Is it possible to aggregate an object?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to aggregate the total sum of packets in this document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51a6cd102769c63e65061bda"),
    "capture" : "1369885967",
    "packets" : {
        "0" : "595",
        "1" : "596",
        "2" : "595",
        "3" : "595",
        ...
    }
}
```

The closest I can get is about

```
db.collection.aggregate({ $match: { capture : "1369885967" } }, {$group: { _id:null, sum: {$sum:"$packets"}}});
```

However it returns sum 0, which is obviously wrong.

```
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : null, "sum" : 0 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

How do I get the sum of all the packets?

Comment: You need to `$unwind` that `packets` subdocument, also you will wqant to change that subdocument to an array

Comment: not possible for an object? when would it be appropriate to use an object instead if thats the case?

Comment: Ah you know you got the object....hmm....no

Comment: The reason why you get 0 is because the values are strings and not numbers. You can not generate a sum from strings. Are you sure you mean "sum" the entries and not "count" the entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the values in an object instead of an array, you'll need to use mapReduce.

```
// Emit the values as integers

var mapFunction = 
  function() {
    for (key in this.packets) {
      emit(null, parseInt(this.packets[key]));
    }
  }

// Reduce to a simple sum

var reduceFunction = 
  function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values);
  }

> db.collection.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {out: {inline:1}})
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "value" : 2381
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

If at all possible, you should emit the values as an array of a numeric type instead since that gives you more options (ie aggregation) and (unless the data set is large) probably performance benefits.

Comment: I am contemplating if I should change the structure to store packets as Array instead. I sure will change the packets value to numeric. Any advise with regards to the former considering I may do various queries  like, finding which time as the highest or lowest packets? Basically the various relationships between the time and packets.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many keys are in the packet subdocument and since you also seem to be storing counts as strings (why???) you will have to use mapReduce.

Something like:

```
m=function() { 
    for (f in "this.packets") {
      emit(null, +this.packets[f]);
};
r=function(k, vals) { 
     int sum=0;
     vals.forEach(function(v) { sum+=v; } );
     return sum;
}

db.collection.mapreduce(m, r, {out:{inline:1}, query:{your query condition here}});
```

Comment: Well, yes, it would have worked if packets were an array of numeric type; `"errmsg" : "exception: $unwind:  value at end of field path must be an array"`.

Comment: wait are your number values really stored as strings?

Comment: updated my answer to cater to both strings instead of numbers and unknown number of fields. Sorry, misread the question earlier.