# Aggregate an entire mongodb object using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database containing some large objects, with always the same keys/structure:

```
{
  "stats": {
    "a": 100
    "b": 0
    "c": 30
    "d": 20
    ...
    "z": 100
  }
},
{
  "stats": {
    "a": 200
    "b": 2
    "c": 10
    "d": 40
    ...
    "z": 100
  }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to aggregate all `stats` sub-object without specifying all their fields using PyMongo. The desired output would be this:

```
"stats": {
  "a": 150
  "b": 1
  "c": 20
  "d": 30
  ...
  "z": 100
}
```

I found this: [Mongodb Is it possible to aggregate an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832035/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-aggregate-an-object) but I am kinda unsure of how to use it in PyMongo.

EDIT: I could list all fields and aggregate them, but I am looking for a solution not listing those fields (I have approximately 100 of them).

Comment: I want to confirm that you want to get average of values by each key, is it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in to do what you're asking, at least not that I am aware of.

One thing that you could do is dynamically build the pipeline in Python. Since every document has the same fields, you could do a `find_one` and use that to get the set of fields and build an aggregation pipeline from that.

For example:

```
import pprint
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
db = MongoClient().test
collection = db.foo

pipeline = [{
    '$group': {
        '_id' : None
     }
}]

group = pipeline[0]['$group']

doc = collection.find_one()

for k in doc['stats']:
    group[k] = {'$avg' : '$stats.'+k}


pp.pprint(pipeline)

cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)

for doc in cursor:
    pp.pprint(doc)
```

Output:

```
[   {   '$group': {   '_id': None,
                      u'a': {   '$avg': u'$stats.a'},
                      u'b': {   '$avg': u'$stats.b'},
                      u'c': {   '$avg': u'$stats.c'},
                      u'd': {   '$avg': u'$stats.d'},
                      u'z': {   '$avg': u'$stats.z'}}}]
{   u'_id': None, u'a': 150.0, u'b': 1.0, u'c': 20.0, u'd': 30.0, u'z': 100.0}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way by using a map-reduce function? I can't figure how I could write it, but this solution is a pretty okay start.

Comment: You could probably do this with map reduce, but the aggregation framework is going to perform better. map reduce should be a last resort.